# How to better place data for different tests into one file, one VC? Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a quiz app. Maybe this question is kind of stupid, but I still would like to hear some advice. Say there are three levels of complexity of the tests in a quiz, so a user can opt for one of them at the beginning (say the easiest level, middle level and the hard one). Below is the picture of the three viewControllers (ignore the design for now). My question is: how to better make the passage/passover to the third final step, i.e. from the second ViewController, where you choose one of the levels, to implementing the test itself?

The easiest thing for me (and the only one that I think I know for now) would be to create three separate ViewControllers at this third step of the test with questions.
It means that all the methods and variables will be the same in these three ViewControllers, only `private var questions = [Question(text: "What is 2 + 2?", answers: [Answer, Answer, Answer, Answer]` will differ (depending on the chosen difficulty). And the transition from   LevelsViewController (second step) to GameViewController (third final step) would be easy to do through creating three separate methods `let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "game") as! GameViewController vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`
and then putting these three methods into  the three separate corresponding IBAction functions.

But from a programmers point of view, I don’t think this is the right thing to do.
Maybe it’s better to put all these questions into one ViewController, maybe name differently these three arrays with questions and somehow hook them up to the certain button in LevelsViewController respectively?

But in that case most of the methods in GameViewController should be refactored, changed (because at least you have to take into account three different names of the arrays with questions).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid at all costs copying the whole `GameViewController` code three times! How about declaring a dictionary that maps each difficulty to a list of the questions for that difficulty:

```swift
static let questionSets = [
    "Beginners": [
        Question(...),
        Question(...),
    ],
    "Middle": [
        Question(...),
    ],
    "Advanced": [
        Question(...),
    ],
]
```

Then you might give each `GameViewController` a `questions` property that initially will be `nil`:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    var questions: [Question]!
    ...
}
```

When a button is pressed, we instantiate a `GameViewController` and fill in its `questions` with the correct question set:

```
class LevelsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBAction func didPressButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "game") as! GameViewController
        
        guard let button = sender as? UIButton,
              let buttonText = button.titleLabel?.text else {
            print("Could not get button's text")
            return
        }
        guard let questionSet = GameViewController.questionSets[buttonText] else {
            print("No question set exists for \(buttonText.debugDescription)")
            return
        }
        vc.questions = questionSet
        // Present `vc`
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
    }
}
```

I'm assuming `LevelsViewController` is within a [`UINavigationController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller).

Then in `GameViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`, just use the values in `self.questions` to construct the interface.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for question in self.questions {
            let questionView = QuestionView(question)
            self.view.addSubview(questionView)
            // Do whatever with `questionView`
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The hard part will be designing `QuestionView`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough answer. Sorry for me being slow to catch on, but could you please be more precise, what exactly do I have to write in `viewDidLoad` in `LevelsViewController` ? As for `self.questions` should I declare it again, because I had to get rid of it, comment it out in `GameViewController`, ‘cause instead we are now using `questionSets`. As far as I understood it. @McKinley

Comment: Sure, no problem. I edited my answer with more code and context. Let me know if anything's unclear.

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me. Sorry,  I didn’t get it to the full extent. I mean the last part. 
So first we declare `var questions: [Question]!` in `GameVC`. Then in Model folder we create a new file `QuestionView` (e.g. `struct QuestionView  {
  let question: Question}`).
Then in `viewDidLoad` in `GameVC` I retyped your code above, only the last active line  I had to change to `let questionView = QuestionView(question: question)`, and then here at same spot below I added `view.addSubview(questionView)` @McKinley

Comment: - and because of that last line I added, error pops up _Cannot convert value of type 'QuestionView' to expected argument type ‘UIView'_ 
But I think I ‘ve done everything wrong here.

And one more question: do I have to  add another  `View` or `TableView` in main.storyboard on top of already existing `tableView` which will stand for `QuestionView` in `GameVC`? @McKinley

Comment: Make sure to make `QuestionView` a subclass of `UIView`. Note that since `UIView` is a class, `QuestionView` must also be a class, not a struct.

About my suggestion to add the questions to a table view -- I was assuming you wanted to stack the questions vertically. But I see now that you want just one question displayed at a time, right? Sorry for the misunderstanding -- I've edited my answer again.

Comment: Thanks for useful advice. Did everything like you said. All the errors seemed to disappear. Then I ran the app and an error shows up (when you tap Beginners/Middle/Advanced) _Thread 1: "-[QuizGame.LevelsViewController startGame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc8e0c0e090”_  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RXF9ds601USv2MIaw6PvfB64PwyvTYTD/view?usp=sharing)
By the way, there isn’t any mentioning of UINavigationController in my code. And I also tried to replace `navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` with... @McKinley

Comment: ... with `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(vc, animated: true)`.
But it makes no difference, the error is still the same. On Stackoverflow there are at least a couple of links, where the same problem is being discussed, but there are lots of reasons, and I haven’t detected mine yet.  Yes, you are right, I want just one question being displayed at a time. @McKinley

Comment: It’s a bit diverting from the topic, but I have to say that. I just misread one recommendation and decided to leave only one button (in my case `Advanced`) hooked up with the `@IBAction func startGame` in `LevelsVC` (you above called this func `didPressButton`). So I detached two other buttons (`Beginners`, `Middle`) only right clicking on them in the storyboard and pressing the cross on TouchUpInside in Sent Events. Reloaded the app, pressed the only active button `Advanced`, the error still remained the same, the problem persisted. So I simply wanted to hook up back again those 2 buttons..

Comment: ... those two detached buttons, ctrl dragged them into `@IBAction func startGame`, and now the error which appears after these two buttons is different: _Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)_. It crashed in class QuestionView, which I had created myself [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jqQxN6NZ-l62q4b3Y-YVjMgMPaqmiq41/view?usp=sharing).
The only difference that I could find is a colon sign after right clicking on the button in Sent Events (after ‘startGame). There is a colon in changed buttons, and no colon in `Advanced` button,that hadn’t been detached...

Comment: ... button, that hadn’t been detached and hooked up again. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10RbSJO8bK8I-_4LxfmQYSaYZmPBsk65e/view?usp=sharing).Maybe didn’t unhook those two buttons completely? Maybe I had to unhook them also in some other place/places?  @McKinley

Comment: Removed my `@IBAction func startGame(_ sender: Any)`in `LevelsVC`, detached all three buttons, created this func all over again, hooked everything up, now the only error after tapping any button is: _Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)_ in class `QuestionView`. The link was attached earlier. So it seems I created class `QuestionView` incorrectly. @McKinley

Comment: Open up the [Xcode console](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html) to view the error message: `Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:)' for class 'QuestionView'`. The problem is that `UIView.init()` calls `UIView.init(frame:)` by default, which hasn't been implemented by `QuestionView`. I recommend calling `super.init(frame: /* some frame */)` in `QuestionView.init(question:)`.

Comment: I recommend using a navigation controller to present view controllers rather than calling `present(_:,animated:)`. The latter method slides the presented VC into the screen from the bottom, while the former method slides it in from the right, which feels more natural. Navigation controllers also provide "back" buttons by default. It would be a good idea to make your app's root VC a navigation controller.

Comment: Great! It started to work! I just added `super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))` in `init(question: Question)` like you said. Besides it works regardless of the values in these coordinates and dimensions. So I think this question is closed. Thank you a lot! @McKinley

Comment: As for the navigation controller,  as far as I remember from sundry videos you have to take it first from the bottom of the screen in storyboard from so called embedded options. But in examples it served only to the first and only screen, and I have got 2-3 of them. So I first have to figure that out how it works. Sure, I will look into it. Thanks for advice! @McKinley

Comment: By the way I already started (when the question had not been closed yet) reading the article [link](https://stevenpcurtis.medium.com/subclassing-uiview-in-swift-d372c67b7f3). Where they quote Apple that it’s recommended to subclass UIView only when the standard system views don’t provided the capabilities needed. But I still gonna read this article till the end for common understanding. ) @McKinley